# Spring: Why the SessionFactoryUtils class in Hibernate 4 does not provide the getSession method?

Tags: spring, hibernate-4.x

What happened to the SessionFactoryUtils.getSession method from Hibernate 4 in Spring 3.1.0  ?  What should be used instead ? sessionFactory.getCurrentSession() keeps giving me this exception:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:97)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:883)
```

Any hint ?

Comment: I am facing same problem, I am using sessionFactory.getCurrentSession() instead, but I am not sure if it is the right way to go.

Answer (score 5):

Use `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()`

I believe the concept of a *"current session"* came in Hibernate 3, `SessionFactoryUtil` was written before this existed.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why did they remove it, probably they implemented a better design using `org.hibernate.context.CurrentSessionContext`. As from [this post](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?117227-Missing-Hibernate-Classes-Interfaces-in-spring-orm-3.1.0.RC1#post_386881):

> ... Simply use the plain SessionFactory and use the getCurrentSession
>   method to obtain the current transactional session (don't use
>   openSession!!!!) and you are good to go...

As from [documentation of SessionFactory.getCurrentSession()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html#getCurrentSession%28%29):

```
The definition of what exactly "current" means controlled by the CurrentSessionContext impl configured for use.
```

Comment: in marten's post, the key word is "current *transactional* session". So, gastaldi must set up transactional demarcation like I describe in my answer

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a property example:

`<prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>`

to your session factory bean mapping. (check the hibernate documentation for more details)

Answer (score 0):

The '`org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread`' exception happens when you haven't configured your transaction demarcation properly with Spring.

Typically, Spring opens a session for you when your transaction starts, binds it to a ThreadLocal and re-uses it for the duration of your transaction. When your transaction commits, the session is closed (after it was flushed). So, you don't need to make any calls to the `SessionFactory` class yourself.

Usually, people put `@Transactional` on a class (typically a Service) and [configure Spring to start and end transactions on method invocations](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations) on that class.